# Class Not Found Exception, even after putting the jar file and setting the classpath in Mac OS X

Tags: java, mysql, macos, jdbc, odbc

I am trying to make a java application which would use MySQL as database. I have successfully done this number of times using Windows but I am facing problems with Mac OS. Even after placing the "my sql connector" jar file in lib folder and setting proper classpath, I am getting an exception of

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcnNF.jpg) of code along with exception.

Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to connect to MySQL, you need to use the right Driver class - see [MySQL Documentation on MySQL Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html)

```
public class LoadDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // The newInstance() call is a work around for some
            // broken Java implementations

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // handle the error
        }
    }
}
```

Please note, your JDBC url is also wrong, or do you try to connect via odbc? (MySQL JDBC URL for example: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase` , driver class: `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`)